# Open the page from a standard browser

Tags: office-js

There is a download function in my add-in, but after testing, I found that only by using location.href and window.open to access the address outside the domain can I open the external browser. However, my download function is not outside the domain, so could you please tell me how I can solve this problem

```
window.location.href = ajaxPath +'/index.php/AdproWorkPlace/downExcelMessage?USERIDDATA='+msg;
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.href` will open inside of the taskpane, which is by design. if you want to open the url in external standard browser, you may try `Office.context.ui.openBrowserWindow(url)` to launch the URL in the default browser outside of excel, you could try the following code in script lab.

```
Office.context.ui.openBrowserWindow("https://github.com");
```

Comment: I have tested it in srCIPtLab, which allows me to open a browser and access my URL, but it still doesn't work in the project code

Comment: which app are you using?

Comment: The application I use is office2019